# model=smf.ols("Employee Salary~Years Experience",data=Salary).fit() SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I tried running this code to fit model for simple linear regression

```py
model=smf.ols("Employee Salary~Years Experience",data=Salary).fit()
```

but I am getting an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-38-5f905976ebf4>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    model=smf.ols("Employee Salary~Years Experience",data=Salary).fit()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 203, in from_formula
    tmp = handle_formula_data(data, None, formula, depth=eval_env,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/statsmodels/formula/formulatools.py", line 63, in handle_formula_data
    result = dmatrices(formula, Y, depth, return_type='dataframe',

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 309, in dmatrices
    (lhs, rhs) = _do_highlevel_design(formula_like, data, eval_env,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 164, in _do_highlevel_design
    design_infos = _try_incr_builders(formula_like, data_iter_maker, eval_env,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/highlevel.py", line 66, in _try_incr_builders
    return design_matrix_builders([formula_like.lhs_termlist,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/build.py", line 689, in design_matrix_builders
    factor_states = _factors_memorize(all_factors, data_iter_maker, eval_env)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/build.py", line 354, in _factors_memorize
    which_pass = factor.memorize_passes_needed(state, eval_env)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 478, in memorize_passes_needed
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 478, in <listcomp>
    subset_names = [name for name in ast_names(self.code)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patsy/eval.py", line 109, in ast_names
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    Employee Salary
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix this?

Comment: My (wild) guess is that the spaces in your column names are causing the issue. Try removing the spaces in the dataframe *and* formula

Comment: Show us the full code.  I suspect there is a mismatched quote or parenthesis on a previous line.

Comment: use quote `Q("...")` in formula if names are not valid python names. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986987/statsmodels-linear-regression-model-doesnt-work-because-of-the-invalid-syntax/71015524#71015524     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69612661/why-does-python-say-that-a-value-does-not-exist-when-it-specifically-does/69612857#69612857

Comment: As a part of EDA, i tried changing the column name-Salary=Salary.rename({'YearsExperience': 'Years Experience','Salary': 'Employee Salary'},axis=1)
now i tried using underscore- it worked now..